# USA IT industry - How to deal with coworker who was found to have fake resume?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, resume, management, fraud

I work as a junior QA engineer in a big IT company in **USA**. My manager informed me that they discovered that one senior (yes, "senior") full-time, QA engineer in my team had actually lied on his resume about his experience in programming/automation. They found out that he has hardly any knowledge of automation and are now seeing if they can get him up to speed on automation. This is no surprise to me because he cannot even think about basic manual testing tasks, let alone automate manual tasks. No wonder I had to to do the work which he was expected to do. I had seen the signs well before the upper management had.

Ideally, I would like to have that co worker fired, because he lied and it was a major lie. Moreover, he often needs help for simple tasks which any reasonable person would expect a QA of "senior" experience to perform on his own.

Alternately, I would like him to be demoted to a very junior position and then rise from there if he proves the ability to learn and improve quickly. I strongly doubt that, given the low caliber of the faker.

I know that these are not decisions for me to make, but how do I voice my concerns to the upper management ? As an aside, it feels unfair that such a person might potentially be earning more than us & that he might have gotten a bonus.

**PS** -

I know that this problem occurs on a bigger, almost industrial scale. I wonder how or if I should mention this to my manager. **Please see the first link I posted, to get some perspective.**

In **USA**, there are many "medium" to "small"/nondescript **IT contracting firms** whose "contractors" have little to no experience. Such firms encourage junior contractors/newbies to use **fake resumes** to get contracting gigs for roles that require several years of experience.

The phone/video interviews are done by proxy and the reference checks are taken care of (most experience is in tiny nondescript IT companies). If the contractor manages to get the gig, then part or whole of his work is off shored to experienced workers who complete his work for a few months to a year, until he has learned enough to survive. If he can continue pulling this off for 3+ years, then he can remove the fake experience, put his genuine 3+ years experience & apply for jobs with real experience.

https://www.nbcbayarea.com/news/local/Jobseekers-Warn-of-Fake-Resumes-from-Fremont-Staffing-Firm-Beta-Soft-Systems-324236081.html

https://www.happyschools.com/consultant-training-faking-resume/

[Staffing companies ask to put fake experience: Ethical or Unethical](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/86672/staffing-companies-ask-to-put-fake-experience-ethical-or-unethical)

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/techniques-identifying-fake-resumes-usa-surjith-sajeeva-kumar

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Answer (score 8):

Upper management is already aware and they will deal with it. Do not get involved, it just makes you look malicious and attempting to preempt management.

I'm more concerned that upper management is communicating such sensitive information to a junior. That is a huge failing on their part unless there is something I am missing.

Comment: They communicated this to me because I deliberately dropped hints and proof that this person is impacting my work. He is not able to do basic tasks quite often.

Comment: You have direct communication over your managers head with upper management? What sort of cowboy company is this?

Comment: ok, I updated the question. It was my manager who informed me, i.e. "upper management".

Comment: So all management is already involved, problem has been passed on to those who can deal with it, if you have a personal issue with the person take it up on your own behalf directly with them

Answer (score 3):

The higher ups know about it, and told you to upskill him.

Seems like your duties are pretty clear.

Either they knew all along or found out and want to keep it quiet for some reason.  Act against this person at your own risk.  Last time I heard of something like this, the person had the protection of an Executive Vice President.

If they knew about it and did nothing and then told you to bring him up to speed and you don't, It's time to update YOUR resume.

Comment: I have not been asked to get him up to speed. But, it appears that the understanding is that management will be lenient with him, for reasons that are unknown to me. It does not appear that he has some special connection, but I can't be sure.

Comment: @TheFakeResumeScam if you're not sure, don't stick your neck out.  Do your job, help him as much as management requires you to, and don't get involved in office politics.  He'll either get up to speed or he won't  That's management's concern not yours.  Even if he's not protected, you won't look good if you try to push him out the door.

Comment: @TheFakeResumeScam I understand why you WANT to see him fired.  I agree he deserves to be fired.  However, life is not always fair, and sometimes the fakers get away with it.  If you can't make your peace with that, perhaps you should start asking yourself how much you want to be employed by this company, given the stance they take on such things.

Comment: @Steve-O don't forget the two biggest fakers who made it:  Bill Gates and Steve Jobs.